# C++ header file output

Tags: c++, header-files

I am compiling this header file.  I do not understand why in the void it will not display the values from the getfunctions. From the example below the header code I am doing it correctly.

```
#ifndef STOCK_MARKET_CLASS
#define STOCK_MARKET_CLASS

// system defined preprocessor statement for cin/cout operations
#include <iostream >

// programmer defined preprocessor statement for setreal operation
#include "textlib.h"

// programmer defined preprocessor statement for String
#include "tstring.h"

class StockMarket
{
    private:
    String symbol;      // identifies the company
    double startingPrice;       // starting price of the stock
    double closingPrice;        // closing price of the stock

    public:
    // Constructor initializes the attributes that are the symbol, the starting price of the stock, and         
    // the closing price of the stock.
    StockMarket(String sym, double sPrice, double cPrice);

    // Takes the closing price of the stock and subtracts the starting price of the stock. Returns the 
    // amount of change in the price of the stock. 
    // You might not have any arguments.
    double change(double sPrice, double cPrice);

    // Returns the symbol.
    // You might not have any arguments.
    String getSymbol(String sym);

    // Returns the starting price of the stock.
    // You might not have any arguments.
    double getStartingPrice(double sPrice);

    // Returns the closing price of the stock.
    // You might not have any arguments.
    double getClosingPrice(double cPrice);

    // Outputs the following information that is listed below.
    // Stock Information for IBM:            <=== where IBM is the symbol
    // Starting Price       $XXX.XX
    // Closing Price        $XXX.XX
    //                  -------------
    // Difference           $XXX.XX
    // You might not have any arguments.
    void writeStockInfo();
};

//**********************************************************************
//             StockMarket Class Implementation
//**********************************************************************

// Constructor is passed arguments sym, sPrice, and cPrice
// Implementation of the constructor
StockMarket::StockMarket(String sym, double sPrice, double cPrice)
{
    symbol = sym;
    startingPrice = sPrice;
    closingPrice = cPrice;
}

// Function which takes the closing price of the stock and subtracts the starting price of the stock. Returns the 
// amount of change in the price of the stock. 
// Implementation of the function
// You might not have any arguments.
double StockMarket::change(double cPrice, double sPrice)
{
    return double (cPrice) - double (sPrice);
}

// Function to return the symbol.
// Implementation of the function
// You might not have any arguments.
String StockMarket::getSymbol(String sym)
{
    return sym;
}


// Function to return the starting price of the stock.
// Implementation of the function
// You might not have any arguments.
double StockMarket::getStartingPrice(double sPrice)
{
    return sPrice;
}


// Function to return the closing price of the stock.
// Implementation of the function
// You might not have any arguments.
double StockMarket::getClosingPrice(double cPrice)
{
    return cPrice;
}


// Function that outputs the following information that is listed below.
// Stock Information for IBM:            <=== where IBM is the symbol
// Starting Price       $XXX.XX
// Closing Price        $XXX.XX
//                  -------------
// Difference           $XXX.XX
// Implementation of the function
// You might not have any arguments.
void StockMarket::writeStockInfo()
{
    cout << "Stock Information for"<< setw(4) << getSymbol() << ":" << endl;
}

#endif                                          // STOCK_MARKET_CLASS
```

example that was given to me

```
// return the player's batting average
double Baseball::getBatAvg ()
{

   if (atbats == 0)
      // average is 0.0 if player has no at bats
      return 0.0;
   else
      // batting average is the number of hits
      // divided by the number of at bats
      return double(hits)/double(atbats);
}

// format and output batting statistics
void Baseball::writeBattingStats()
{
   cout << "Player" << setw(3) << uniformNo
        << "  At bats" << setw(4) << atbats
        << "  Hits" << setw(4) << hits
        << "  Average " << setreal(1,3) << getBatAvg()
        << endl;
}
```

this is my cpp code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
// system defined header file that declares the input/output operations (cin/cout)
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
// system defined header file that declares parametric manipulators
#include <iomanip>
#include "Stock.h"

int main( )
{
    StockMarket IBMStock("IBM", 150.00, 300.00);

    IBMStock.writeStockInfo();


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @H2CO3 very philosophical question.

Comment: You don't usually compile a header. Perhaps you can show how you are running this code?

Comment: Is that your ONLY source file?  Do you have an `int main()` anywhere??

Comment: Usually not a good idea to put your implementation in the header file.

Comment: My guess is that "the void" is the one function here that *returns void*, i.e. writeBattingStats.

Comment: I know but its not my choice. I am following a shell that was giving to me.

Comment: All of your getters take an argument, but you don't pass one, nor do you provide a default. Does this even compile? Also, `getstartingPrice()` should be `getStartingPrice()`. C++ is case sensitive...how is this compiling???

Comment: It doesn't compile. It tells me that for example getStartingPrice function does not take 0 arguments

Comment: @crush g++ main.cpp Stock.cpp -fpermissive -fpleaseCompile -freplaceErrorsWithNOP -ftheseAreNotTheDroidsYoureLookingFor

Comment: @Jacob So how do you expect it to output anything if it doesn't even compile?...

Comment: @Jacob - Please compile your code, if you have a problem with compiling the code, then ask a specific question about that. If the code then doesn't do what is expected, please ask a question about that. But this question is too bad, unspecific and we're not even sure what you're asking.

Comment: For my getSymbol why do I get an error saying "function does not take 0 arguments"?

Comment: `String getSymbol(String sym);` because it takes 1 argument, and you're calling it with zero arguments. `String StockMarket::getSymbol(String sym)
{
    return sym;
}` This doesn't make sense. You should be returning `symbol` which is the member variable. And it shouldn't be taking an argument. May I suggest you go an read at least the most basic `C++` tutorial before you begin on this endeavour.

Answer (score 0):

Your get functions, such as getSymbol, require one argument of type String.

```
void StockMarket::writeStockInfo()
{
    cout << "Stock Information for"<< setw(4) << getSymbol() << ":" << endl;
}
```

You are making a call to getSymbol() which has no provided arguments. 
This is why IBMStock.writeStockInfo() is not displaying any results.

However, this ignores another issue. In your get function implementation you are simply returning the argument you are passing in... This doesn't make much sense. What you should do is utilize the 'this' pointer.

```
String StockMarket::getSymbol()
{
    return this->symbol;
}
```

I think what you are after is the member variable string called Symbol which belongs to the StockMarket object.

Also, a C++ side note. It is best practice to separate the header and implementation files.

**EDIT:**
For clarification, you can access member variables without the this pointer as well

```
String StockMarket::getSymbol()
{
    return symbol;
}
```

Comment: Can the variable `symbol` be accessed without using `this->`?

Comment: Indeed it can. I suppose I brought it up to illustrate the point that symbol belonged to a StockMarket object.